# Log4j doesn't see .properties file

Tags: java, log4j

I use log4j for logging in my app. In every class I need to log something I have the following:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream("/log4j.properties"));
    } catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error(e);
    }
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

log4j.properties is placed to the folder /src/main/resources/

the path /log4.properties is given by IDEA as copy reference. When I start my app it it shows the FileNotFoundException

Comment: Don't use `FileInputStream`, use your `Class#getResourceAsStream()` since the file is on the classpath. Also you shouldn't need to load log4j properties yourself.

Comment: If I don't load log4j.properties myself I get something like "log4j no config found. Configure log4j properly"

Comment: Where are you putting the file?

Comment: that was not /src/main/resources/

Comment: That's where it should be. You must be doing something else differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `FileInputStream`.

The `java.io` and its consorts work with the current working directory i.e the directory from which the JVM is executed and not the code workspace.

to illustrate this consider the following piece of code

```
class ReadFrmFile {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FileInputStream fin = New FileInputStream("intemp.txt");
    }
}
```

If the code is executed from `C:\TEMP` , the `intemp.txt` is expected to be in the working directory(`C:/TEMP`) in this case. If not this will throw the `FileNotFoundException`. The path of the file names are always absolute and not relative.

To avoid hardcoding the best way would be to place all the required files in the classpath and load them using `getResourceAsStream`().

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream inStream = **YOUR_CLASS_NAME**.class.getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties");
        props.load(inStream);
    } catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error(e);
    }
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

Answer (score 1):

log4j, by default, looks for the `log4j.properties` file in the classpath, so you don't need to use the class `PropertyConfigurator`, ony if the file doesn't exist in the root of the classpath.

In the [Spring MVC + Log4j Integration Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/), you will see:

[image]